# Swift - How can i check if firebase server is available or not?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I want to check if Firebase server is available or not.
How can i check this?

Comment: Attempt  an operation, handle the error

Comment: Which Firebase service are you talking about?

Comment: Firestore and Realtime database

Answer (score 0):

I'd just do the operations and handling the errors properly.

Most likely Firebase will be always available and eventual errors can be easily addressed.

If you wanna take a look on their status history, they have this dashboard:

https://status.firebase.google.com